# add wishlist in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i'm new in rails hope you could help me with this
i have services, users, and wishlist and every user has their wishlist
how do i make the method to pass the service to the user wishlist
for example: i see a service that i like, and put add to my wishlist from a buttom and automatically upload that to my wishlist. 
thanks 
i'm using devise. 
service model

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :user_id
```

user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :service
  has_one :wishlist
```

wishlist model

```
class Wishlist < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_and_belongs_to_many :service
```

db table

```
class CreateWishlists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :wishlists do |t|

        t.integer :wishlist_id
        t.references :user, foreign_key: true
        t.references :service, foreign_key: :true

        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: so what you want is kind of like a favorite kind of thing? Check this post which can be nice for favorites: http://schmidt-happens.com/articles/2014/06/04/favoriting-system-in-rails.html

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just push params into your wishlist controller you should add a link where you submit the params with:

= link_to 'add to wish', wishlist_path(current_user, @service)
and than save this stuff via controller into your Wishlist DB